# ocaml sdl chunk garbage collection

Tags: garbage-collection, ocaml, sdl

So here's the deal: at first I thought the following was some really sexy code for playing and then freeing a wav file when it is finished, without freezing the machine with a delay command (assuming the program is and will be doing stuff for the duration of the wav file, i.e., not exiting, when the function is called):

```
let rec play_wav file play =
   Sdlmixer.open_audio ~freq:44100 ();
   let loaded_file = Sdlmixer.loadWAV file in
   if play = false then
     Sdlmixer.free_chunk loaded_file
   else 
     (
       Sdlmixer.play_channel ~loops:1 loaded_file;
       play_wav file false
     )
 ;;
```

I should also say there are probably better ways of accomplishing the same task, and it might only work because of machine particular features, etc., but now I have just an academic curiosity about whether:

(1) the file is being loaded twice, and freed only once, thus making decidedly unpretty code;

or, contrariwise,

(2) whether the wav file loaded twice by Sdlmixer.loadWAV is *not* assigned two separate memory addresses, mallocs, etc., or in separation logic h = (h1 * *emp*) is a post-condition ;)  In other words, if once loaded, loading it again is operationally ineffectual, and a single free will free the chunk, no matter how many times it was loaded.

and lastly, whether

(3) the Sdlmixer.free_chunk is even necessary, since the similar free_surface C function for the OCaml-sdl libraries is not implemented.

Running valgrind on all of the below does not seem to indicate memory leaks:

(a) a program containing the play_wav function,

(b) with a function that fails to free the chunk,

(c) with a sequential load-play-wait-free_chunk code block,

(d) with a function that loads the same wav file 1000 times.

(Actually, and technically, in every case it states "definitely lost: 337 bytes in 4 blocks", not sure what that's about, but regardless valgrind reports the same memory results for all four cases.)

I imagine in the case of (b) OCaml's garbage collector takes care of this when the program terminates, so its hard to say if its still loaded and taking up memory after that particular routine finishes, and hence needs freeing, since when the function finishes the program terminates, so it probably is a good idea to use the free chunk function in larger programs.

Anyway, was just wondering what people's thoughts and opinions on this might be.

Comment: I guess I'm going to have to wait until the Europeans wake up to get some feedback ;)

Comment: look at the implementation of sdl bindings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From perusing the source code of the library, it appears to me that chunk values aren't automatically garbage collected, so you have to free them explicitly, or setup your own handler to do that (see Gc.finalize).

It is strange to me that valgrind doesn't report any significant problem.

Your code is indeed loading the sample twice if the parameter play is true on the initial invocation.
I suppose you need the play parameter outside the fact that you are using it to stop and release the sample in the function.

Perhaps something like:

```
let play_wav = function
     true -> (fun file ->
     Sdlmixer.open_audio ~freq:44100 ();
     let loaded_file = Sdlmixer.loadWAV file in
     Sdlmixer.play_channel ~loops:1 loaded_file;
     Sdlmixer.delay 1000;
     Sdlmixer.free_chunk loaded_file;
     Sdlmixer.close_audio ())
    | _   -> (fun _ -> ())
```

could fit your need. I swapped the two parameters of play_wav, so as to make it more obvious to the compiler that it doesn't have anything to do when play is false. If you pass false explicitly, the function should be optimized away (I believe).
I added the close_audio call that was missing, and a delay to give the mixer some time to play the sample. 
Now, if you need to play the same sample many times, it might be more interesting to cache it to avoid reloading it later on.

Comment: Sorry this took 3 years; I got lost on the way to the bathroom.

Comment: Perhaps you could try using a GPS to find your way? :)